# Changing Pagination based on screen size

Tags: views, paging

Is it possible to change the amount pagination displays based on screen size? For example: I have a products page that I want to show 30 items on desktop, but on mobile I'd like it to only show 10 items.

I'm currently using the Loads More Views module, but that doesn't do what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: The server doesn't know the screen size before it generates the HTML. The only way to do what you are suggesting would be to detect the screen size first, then redirect to one of two different views based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not ideal, but better than nothing.